# How to align an element under a piece of right aligned text?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a user comment thing in HTML. I would like it to look similar to [vimeo's](http://vimeo.com/3555366) comments, with the user icon and the text aligned to the right of it. Here is my markup(using a bootstrap container but i dont really think that is the problem):

```
<div class="comment">
<img src="{{comment.poster.profile.avatar.url}}"  alt="...">
<span><a href="profile link">poster name</a>&nbsp;time</span>
<p>comment body</p>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.comment{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: left;
width: 800px;
padding: 10px;
  background-color: @secondary;

 img{
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

The `<span><a href="profile link">poster name</a>&nbsp;time</span>` aligns with the top right of the image just how I want it to, but the body text ends up  under the image, not under the info like where I want it to be. Here is an image of it, arrow is pointing where I want the text to go:

[image]

Any idea how I should do this? I'm real bad at aligning things, so sorry if this is a simple mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look into css `float:right` ? You can add that image in a div and text into another div. Then look out to apply `float:right` for the div.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you canc achieve this:

`<div class="pic">
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
    </div>
    <div class="pic-meta">
        <span>
            <a href="profile link">poster name</a>
            &nbsp;time
        </span>
        <span class="comment">comment</span>
    </div>`

and css:

`.pic, .pic-meta {
        float: left;
    }
    .comment {
        display: block;
    }`

http://jsfiddle.net/p4K7u/